# Categories not visible while adding product

Tags: magento-1.8, category, category-tree

i have never face such issue before, i am not sure why is this happening. 
While adding product i am not able to access subcategories for one of the parent category.

[image]

I am not getting any option to expand tree for "Sport Nutrition" category.

Can any one please help me out?

Thank You.

Comment: The categories are loaded via AJAX. Maybe the call times out? Check the AJAX call and the response body.

Comment: Actually, problem was with incorrect child_count. I got solution from http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/solving-problems-with-category-tree-database-information/

Comment: Please answer your own question and mark it in 2 days as solution :-)