# Cannot add product to category - cannot expand category tree - see image

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm wanting to add a product to a category but it does not show in the product admin panel. The category is there under 'Manage Categories' and the top level shows but not any of the subcats.

There is a small search glass in the corner. Im not getting any error messages, it's just not there.

The image will explain more - [image: Search Glass on folder]

Ver - 1.9.3.3

Any insight would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: can you able to expand that category and add products from `Catalog > Manage categories` section ?

Comment: Hi, yes. I can add the product to the category under Manage Categories, and then it all shows fine on the product admin page. But only for that product. The rest I still cannot.

Comment: someone [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21286/categories-not-visible-while-adding-product) solved issue using [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/solving-problems-with-category-tree-database-information/) , better wait for some more time, so you may get some easy solution from someone else....

Comment: please follow some links from [here](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=mkFvWaDYMKiIX8LdvZgP&gws_rd=ssl#q=magento+cannot+expand+category+tree)

Comment: Brilliant, that worked. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow below links  :

http://inchoo.net/magento/solving-problems-with-category-tree-database-information/

[Magento category tree not showing all sub categories when adding a new product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38394/magento-category-tree-not-showing-all-sub-categories-when-adding-a-new-product)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993934/magento-category-tree-is-not-shoing-in-category-edit-and-product-edit

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192396/magento-doesnt-show-all-the-categories-in-admin